# How can I get Value of Model Iteration in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a nested Array Object(s) like this that is being fetched:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "category": null,
            "incomingDate": "2021-08-30T18:55:36.000Z",
            "rawIncomingDocumentId": "51262e53-5bf2-3cd3-8465-71f955ce27aa",
            "caseId": null,
            "caseCode": "PAq9T",
            "description": "Accusantium tenetur et similique vitae vitae placeat. Omnis voluptatum enim eaque modi odit. Esse dolores molestias earum qui quaerat itaque expedita. Quisquam ipsam placeat ea aut.",
            "id": "c65e9b83-edbe-3a11-9af7-72193e1e6f51",
            "clientId": "23231337",
            "mimeType": "application/msword",
            "filename": "tempore.doc",
            "createdAt": "2021-08-29T13:29:24+00:00",
            "content": null,
            "metaData": {
                "pages": 1
            },
            "url": "http://localhost:8081/documents/23231337/c65e9b83-edbe-3a11-9af7-72193e1e6f51",
            "sourceId": "ovXu2",
            "type": "incoming.unclassified",
            "taskId": null,
            "clientName": "",
            "origin": "post"
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside my Component, I want to have a download button with the document URL, so a user can click this button to download the document.

Currently, the (child component) download button is inside a table (parent component). The values like date, filename, etc. are rendered in a loop and used inside a `{{value}}` syntax.

How can I fill in the document URL inside the value/property of the button to address this value to a download function? `value={{item.url}}` is obviously not working.
I wrote the needed info inside the button value (DOM), but I don't know how to fetch this.

component

```
<v-data-table
      class="elevation-1"
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :loading="loading"
      show-select
      :search="search"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.incomingDate="{ value }">
        <NeosRunningTimeDate :value="value" />
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.origin="{ value }">
        {{ getOriginsText(value) }}
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.filename="{ item }">
        <a
          class="neos-link"
          href="#"
          @click="
            openPdfWindow(
              {
                documents: { documentId: item.id },
                configuration: { hasEdit: false, hasCategories: false, hasDownload: false },
              },
              locale,
            )
          "
        >
          <v-icon small color="secondary">mdi-file-pdf-outline</v-icon>
          {{ item.filename }}
        </a>
        <v-btn
          elevation="2"
          small
          raised
          rounded
          :value="item.url"
          @click="downloadItem($event)"
          ><v-icon dark>
            mdi-download-circle
          </v-icon></v-btn
        >
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

function

```
  function downloadItem(e) {
      downloadUrl.value = e.target.value;
      console.log('triggerd: ', downloadUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the value directly

```html
<v-btn
  elevation="2"
  small
  raised
  rounded
  @click="downloadItem(item.url)"
  ><v-icon dark> mdi-download-circle </v-icon></v-btn
>
```

```js
function downloadItem(downloadUrl) {
  console.log('triggerd: ', downloadUrl);
}
```